# How to make Uri reference to a Resource image embedded in the assembly itself?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, uri

In my assembly project I have a .png image which it's Build Action is set to Resource.

Now I want to make the following:

```
_myIcon = new BitmapImage(new Uri(**path to the image embedded on the assembly**));
```

I have looked into the examples in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx but as far as I tried gives me "Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.". I don't think this should be a complicated matter, am I taking the wrong approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The other answer is valid but doesn't produce a BitmapSource.

The correct answer, given that I have a folder called Images and inside an Image with the Build Action set to Resource, is to use a [Resource File Pack URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8):

```
_myIcon = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/MyImage.png");
```

Answer (score 2):

For me it worked with something like this

```
String filename = this.GetType().Namespace + ".Resources.myimg.bmp";
//or String.Join if you like
_myIcon = Bitmap.FromStream(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                                .GetManifestResourceStream(filename))
```

So FromStream + GetManifestResourceStream should be the magic words

Comment: The `GetManifestResourceStream` is returning null for some reason. Is it enough to put Build Action = Resource for the image to be embedded or I need something more? I tried some variations of the `filename` without success too. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Build Action have to `Embedded Resource` and not `Resource`.

Comment: @RohitVats That seems so obvious, I feel dumb for not noticing. Thanks, now it's not returning null anymore.

Comment: what namespace is the class Bitmap in?